# How to trigger Azure Logic App if an email is not received from a specific user?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am using a Azure logic app connected with Outlook mail box. I need to trigger it when the e-mail comes to the mailbox other than a single specific from address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement, just configure your trigger like below:

[image]

And do not add the parameter `From`

[image]

==============================**Update**===========================

For your requiements, there are two solutions.

**1.** Create a folder named "From hury shen"(out of "Inbox" folder) and create a rule in your outlook to filter all of the emails from Hury Shen to this new folder.

[image]

[image]

After that, I test it in my side, the logic app will not be triggered when a new email from hury shen arrives.

**2.** The other way is to add a "Condition" in your logic app. If `From` address equal to the specific email address, do nothing. If `From` address not equal to the specific email address, do what you want.

[image]

Comment: If I am removing the From address there, then all the email received in the inbox will get triggered. But i need to restrict a single email alone from the trigger condition.

Comment: Example: If e-mail comes from Hury Shen, then don't trigger....if e-mail comes from other than Hury Shen, then trigger....

Comment: Hi @sabariprabu I'm sorry that misunderstood your requirement. I have modified my answer, please refer to the "Update" part.

Comment: Hi @sabariprabu May I know if the update solution works ?